# Ler todo o conteúdo de um arquivo de texto

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo

Eu preciso ler todo o conteúdo de um arquivo de texto e colocá-lo em uma *string*.

Geralmente, eu faço assim:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader("arquivo.txt"))
{
    var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while (objReader.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        strBuilder.Append(objReader.ReadLine());
    }
}

var texto = strBuilder.ToString();
```

Existe outra forma ou algum método que faça isso de uma maneira mais simples?

Comment: Um dia, quando eu for estudar C#, vou me lembrar dessa pergunta :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No .NET Framework **2.0** e posteriores, a classe `File` tem o método [`ReadAllText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx) que faz exatamente isso.

O código acima ficaria assim:

```
var texto = File.ReadAllText("arquivo.txt");
```

Comment: Tá certo, mas a minha é mais completa :P

Answer (score 10):

Sim, tem, desde a **versão 2.0** do .NET Framework existe o [`ReadAllText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_).

```
var texto = File.ReadAllText("arquivo.txt");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ReadAllText.cs).