# Como carregar uma lista de numeros em um ficheiro TXT para uma lista em C#?

Tags: c#, txt

Tenho a seguinte lista de números carregada de uma tabela, e apresenta-se separada pelo caracter "|":

```
40 |16000|20|311258|3
40 |17000|20|857392|5
50 |18000|90|528777|1
60 |19000|20|917336|3
60 |20000|20|850348|3
60 |21000|90|72598 |4
100|36000|20|157884|2
100|37000|20|550902|1
10 |1000 |50|932557|1
10 |2000 |50|410520|1
```

Quero passar esses dados para um vector a partir desse ficheiro TXT.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92567/ler-todo-o-conte%C3%BAdo-de-um-arquivo-de-texto

Comment: Que tipo de vetor??? porque pode ser coloca cada linha em um vetor ou ainda cada linha que represente cada posição?

Answer (score 1):

Usando linq

```
 List<string[]> lista = File.ReadLines("NomeDoArquivo.txt")
                          .Select(line => line.Split('|'))
                          .ToList();
```

- `File.ReadLines("NomeDoArquivo.txt")` para ler o arquivo linha a linha
- `.Select(line => line.Split('|'))` vai dividir a linha pelo |
- `.ToList();` vai mandar tudo pra lista

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja jogar os dados lidos do arquivo num array ou numa lista, o seguinte código servirá:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(lines);

// ou

string[] vect = new string[lines.length];

for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
{
    vect[i] = lines[i];
}
```

Acredito que irá funcionar